# Java Error ';' expected can't find the problem

Tags: java

I get the errorcode

```
u180921.java:2:error: ';' expected
```

in ConText

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;       
import java.util.Scanner

public class u180921 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bitte Zahl eingeben");
        int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
        double z, erg;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int arr[] =  new int[7];

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            acc(i) = sc.next;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            scc[i] += z;
        }

        erg = z / 7;
    }

}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Missing a semicolon at the end of `import java.util.Scanner`

Comment: Your second line of import maybe...

Comment: `u180921.java:2`--> 2 is the line number. Normally in compilation errors, you would also get a hint on line number. Most IDEs like Eclipse and Intellij also let you directly navigate directly to that line.

Comment: `u180921.java:2` means the second line of `u180921.java` and the message after `error:` says what is wrong

Comment: What is acc(i)? Is it suppose to be arr[i]? acc(i) is a function call, you can't assign anything to a function. Also, you haven't defined scc in your code.

Answer (score 0):

variables `z`, `erg` arn't initialized. Semicolon is missing at the end of `import java.util.Scanner`

Working code is

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class u180921{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bitte Zahl eingeben");
        int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
        double z = 0;
        double erg = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int arr[] =  new int[7];

        for(i=0;i<7;i++){
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        }
        for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
            arr[i] += z;
        }
        erg = z / 7;
    }

}
```